# ncurses based menus

Tags: perl, ncurses

How can I build an ncurses based menu? Are there any other solutions for building "menus" for use on the console? I just need an "inter-operating system" (all non-windows :P) solution. Are there any good solutions to build/create menus in perl?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=all&query=ncurses+menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the program `dialog` be sufficient for your needs? It can do basic dialogs and even more complex stuff. Maybe you should look into it.

See http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2807 for some further information.

Ofcourse, this wouldn't be a 100% perl solution.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in your subject line already. That's what `ncurses` is for. I'm sure there are ncurses bindings for perl. For example there is a [curses UI library for perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mdxi/Curses-UI-0.9607/lib/Curses/UI/Tutorial.pod).

The [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) has perl [examples](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/ncurses_programs/perl/).

Comment: Ncurses isn't the right level for a menu interface, there's a wheel to reinvent above it.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [CDK toolkit](http://invisible-island.net/cdk/) and perl bindings for it. there are also [Python bindings](http://pycdk.sourceforge.net/) if you are interested.  This library provides some higher level "widgets" on top of ncurses.

Answer (score 0):

Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907321/ncurses-and-perl-any-guides

> For a good example of using curses
>   with Perl, you might want to pick up a
>   copy of Steven L Kunz's* perl menus''
>   package (menu.pl'') via anonymous FTP
>   from ``ftp.iastate.edu''. It's in the
>   directory /pub/perl as:
>   menu.pl.v3.1.tar.Z